# How to apply dynamic Deeplinking even if the app is installed in both cases

Tags: javascript, java, android, web, android-deep-link

When the url is searched in google search  bar it should be opened in app but when the link is typed in chrome address bar it should work in browser only, how can i achieve this? Behaviour of the app like Amazon app. I can apply normal deeplinking where link is opened from anywhere in the device.